# Translation of 3D system

Tags: graphics, geometry, computer-vision

I have a single of x-y coordinate system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This diagram should represent what you've told me.
The key point, is to express [x2],[y2] in CS1. (I can't use latex here so let's assume that [A] means the vector A, |A| is the length of the vector A)

[v2] = v2x * [x2] + v2y * [y2]

Since we have well defined [v1] and [d2], we can calculate [x']

[x`] = [d2] - [v1]

From [x'] we can calculate x2

[x2] = (|x2|/|x'|)*[x`] = (|x1|/|x'|)*[x'] since |x1| = |x2|

From x2 we can calculate y2, although I don't remember how. It's a simple 90° rotation.
Should be this:

y2x = - x2y
y2y = x2x

Once we have expressed x2,y2 in CS1, we can compute v2

v2 = v2x * [x2] + v2y * [y2] = v2x * (x2x*[x1]+x2y*[y1]) + v2y * (y2x*[x1]+y2y*[y1])
= (v2x*x2x + v2y*y2x)[x1] + (v2x*x2y + v2y*y2y) [y1] // Hope I didn't make any mistake here :)

And finally

[X] = [v1] + [v2]

I think the best option is to create a vector class and do all the math using vector algebra. You just need to define 3 operation: Addition, ScalarMultiplication, 90Rotation.

Comment: two vectors and 2 bases (x-y coordinate). If your bases are coplanar(no need for a third dimension) then this calculation is simplified. Again, the question is: how do you define CS1 and CS2? what information do you have on them?

Comment: You don't have enough informations to do that. In all case, you need to bring your vectors to a common base. Do you have any info on the cameras?

Comment: I've updated my answer according to this description. I still think you lack some data, but may be I'm over-thinking  it.

Comment: If you could draw a graph, I think that would be better than text. Theoretically, given theses vectors, and if I understand what you are saying, you can determine the direction of the xaxis and the position of the origin. This is enough to give you the angle of rotation of CS2 relative to CS1, but still doesn't give you the absolute length of x2 and y2. Remember, there are 3 possible transformations: Translation, Rotation, Scale. We still need to know the later. Unless you know it's equal to 1.

Comment: I've update my answer again :) You'll have to check my calculation, but I think it's a correct approach. I recommend that you try some sample test and compare the results. I tried to avoid all trigonometric calculation by using vector algebra, but you can also find the angles using basic geometry and trigonometric rules.